# Uncover and cover

Tags: overlays

I have the following problem. I was trying to use the uncover command within an equation in my presentation. Is there any command which can do the opposite?

I try to explain my self better. Suppose I have an equation like the following:
[image]

Basically what I would like is to presente an equation contains only x_{1} and 3x_{2}, leaving 6x_{3} hidden and then to cover 3x_{2} and showing up 6x_{3}.

I have inserted the equation in a very simple way:

```
\[
x_{1}+3x_{2}+6x_{3}=15
\]
```

Does someone have an idea about how to do this? I hope I was clear.

Best wishes.

Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
x_{1}\uncover<1,3>{+3x_{2}}\uncover<2,3>{+6x_{3}}=15
```

Note that in this case, the space for the hidden content is reserved. If you don't want this, just use `\only{}` instead.

```
x_{1}\only<1,3>{+3x_{2}}\only<2,3>{+6x_{3}}=15
```

The numbers inside `<>` specify the slides where the contents will be visible.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the slide \thepage}

\[
x_{1}\uncover<1,3>{+3x_{2}}\uncover<2,3>{+6x_{3}}=15
\]
\[
x_{1}\only<1,3>{+3x_{2}}\only<2,3>{+6x_{3}}=15
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes similar to this. The only thing is that I do not want to show the entire three variables equation. I would like to show only an equation with x_{1} and 3x_{2} and then an equation with x_{1} and 6x_{3}. My objective is to say something like: "usually people do this using x_{1} and x_{2}, instead I suggest to use x_{1} and x_{3}"

Comment: I saw your full answer. I think I have the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I tried using \only. it is fine, but still I do not want to show the full equation as I explained in my post above. Is there any way to avoid the full equation? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It just changed the numbers inside < > and worked perfectly.